# Manage DbAdapter in custom SipmleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have class MyCustomAdapter

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
}
```

I have other class called DbAdapter, where I have functions with sql query. I'd like to access functions from class MyCustomAdapter

```
DbAdapter db                  and next I have to add 
db = new DbAdapter(this)
```

but it doesnt work. I tried

```
Contex contex
db = new DbAdapter(contex)   but then I have java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is any way to access my DbAdapter within MyCustomAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `MyCustomAdapter`-class accept a `Context`-object as a parameter:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

  private final Context context;

  public MyCustomAdapter(Context c){
   this.context = c;
  }

}
```

In the calling activity, you can then simply pass `this` for the context.

---

You're getting this error because the DVM tries to invoke a `SimpleCursorAdapter(Context)`-constructor, which does not exist.

The solution to your problem is either explicitly calling a valid constructor of `SimpleCursorAdapter` by using `super(...)` or making the `MyCursorAdapter`-constructor accept the same parameters as one of the `SimpleCursorAdapter`-constructors.

What way to go relies on what you want to do with your Cursor-adapter. If you have constant values for certain constructor-arguments, you can use those, if you don't, you'll need to include them in your `MyCursorAdapter`-constructor.

As an example, this assumes you don't have constant values for any constructor-argument:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

  private final Context context;

  public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to){
   super(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to); // Call the super-
                                                                        // classes constructor
   this.context = context; // Save the context for further use
  }

}
```

Some further information on this might be found [here](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor-super.html).

Comment: I got error: Implicit super constructor SimpleCursorAdapter() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Comment: error on 

    super(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to);

Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

Comment: My mistake, changed that in my post.

Comment: I tried this after change, but I have errors. Here is code of my class http://pastebin.com/zV6Ysm31 I cant call function db.read_lista_produkty_array(id_listy, id_sklepu) because of DbAdapter

Comment: Post the full StackTrace (NOT as a comment).